# Ajax Loading in jqwidgets

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview

I am working in ASP.Net MVC. And using `jqwidgets`'s tree-control in my web page. Code for that tree is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/gettheme.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxtree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fun()
        {

        }
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#jqxTree').on('select',function (event)
            {
                var args = event.args;
                var item = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('getItem', args.element);
                var label = item.label; 
                alert(label);
            });


            // Create jqxTree 
            var theme = getDemoTheme();
            // create jqxTree
            $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ height: '400px', hasThreeStates: true, checkboxes: false, width: '330px', theme: theme });
            $('#jqxCheckBox').jqxCheckBox({ width: '200px', height: '25px', checked: true, theme: theme });
            $('#jqxCheckBox').on('change', function (event) {
                var checked = event.args.checked;
                $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ hasThreeStates: checked });
            });
            $("#jqxTree").jqxTree('selectItem', $("#home")[0]);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id='jqxWidget'>
        <div style='float: left;'>
            <div id='jqxTree' style='float: left; margin-left: 20px;'>
                <ul>
                    <li id='home'>Home</li>
                    <li item-checked='true' item-expanded='true'>Solutions
                        <ul>
                            <li>Education</li>
                            <li>Financial services</li>
                            <li>Government</li>
                            <li item-checked='false'>Manufacturing</li>
                            <li>Solutions
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                                    <li>Mobile</li>
                                    <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                                    <li>Technical communication</li>
                                    <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                                    <li>Web conferencing</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>All industries and solutions</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Products
                        <ul>
                            <li>PC products</li>
                            <li>Mobile products</li>
                            <li>All products</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Support
                        <ul>
                            <li>Support home</li>
                            <li>Customer Service</li>
                            <li>Knowledge base</li>
                            <li>Books</li>
                            <li>Training and certification</li>
                            <li>Support programs</li>
                            <li>Forums</li>
                            <li>Documentation</li>
                            <li>Updates</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Communities
                        <ul>
                            <li>Designers</li>
                            <li>Developers</li>
                            <li>Educators and students</li>
                            <li>Partners</li>
                            <li>By resource
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Labs</li>
                                    <li>TV</li>
                                    <li>Forums</li>
                                    <li>Exchange</li>
                                    <li>Blogs</li>
                                    <li>Experience Design</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Company
                        <ul>
                            <li>About Us</li>
                            <li>Press</li>
                            <li>Investor Relations</li>
                            <li>Corporate Affairs</li>
                            <li>Careers</li>
                            <li>Showcase</li>
                            <li>Events</li>
                            <li>Contact Us</li>
                            <li>Become an affiliate</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div style='margin-left: 60px; float: left;'>       
                <div style='margin-top: 10px;'>
                    <div id='jqxCheckBox'>Three Check States</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

I have to load new child nodes from database in server, whenever a node is expanded. 
if I have following database schema then what can be solution of this problem.

```
ID   Lable ParentID
```

ID is Id of an element and ParentID is Id of its parent. If a node is expanded, then its children have to be find and insert into the tree-control in view. Please help me how to get rid of this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at that jqwidgets sample: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/ajaxloading.htm?web. It is with loading of items on demand through Ajax.